# Merge sort a given list in Python

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

> Problem: Implement merge sort in python. Don’t use Python’s built in sort or sorted. Assume your inputs will be sufficient for the memory you have.

How should I make this code better?

```
def merge_sort(list_sort):
    """splits the list in two parts until each part is left with one member"""

    if len(list_sort) ==  1:
        return list_sort

    if len(list_sort)>= 2:
        x= len(list_sort) / 2
        part_a = list_sort[:x]
        part_b = list_sort[x:]
        sorted_part_a = merge_sort(part_a)
        sorted_part_b = merge_sort(part_b)
        return merge(sorted_part_a, sorted_part_b)

def merge(left , right):
    """merges the two parts of list after sorting them"""
    sorted_list = []
    i = 0
    while left[:] and right[:] :
        if  left [i] > right [i]:
            sorted_list.append(right[i])
            right.remove(right[i])

        else :
            sorted_list.append(left[i])
            left.remove(left[i])

    if left[:]:
            sorted_list.extend(left[:])
    elif right[:] :
            sorted_list.extend(right[:])
    return sorted_list

details = [1, 127, 56, 2, 1, 5, 7, 9, 11, 65, 12, 24, 76, 87, 123, 65, 8,32, 86, 123, 67, 1, 67, 92, 72, 39, 49, 12, 98, 52, 45, 19, 37, 22, 1, 66, 943, 415, 21, 785, 12, 698, 26, 36, 18, 97, 0, 63, 25, 85, 24, 94, 150 ]
print "List to be sorted  = ", details
print "Sorted List = ", merge_sort(details)
```

Comment: it would be better if the memory is sufficient for the input you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some huge inefficiencies in your code.

Every time you right `left[:]` or `right[:]`, it *duplicates* the list!  You do that several times in `merge()`, unnecessarily.

`i = 0` is a pointless variable, the way you have used it: it's just an obfuscated way to say 0.  Furthermore, `right.remove(right[i])` and `left.remove(left[i])` are just `right.pop(0)` and `left.pop(0)` — but more verbose and inefficient.  Finally, it's extremely inefficient to `.remove()` or `.pop()` anything from the head of a list, since it will need to copy every subsequent element over to fill in the void.

So, what you should be doing instead is iterating through the `left` and `right` lists *non-destructively*, using two variables `i` and `j` to keep track of how far you've gone.

Answer (score 3):

## Sort algorithm

- instead of `if len(list_sort)>= 2:`, just use `else:`
- I would get rid of all the steps inbetween.
- `list_sort` sounds too much like `merge_sort`, a method, not like a variable
- to prevent surprises when using this algorithm in Python 3, use `//` for the floor division
- you can use the fact `1 // 2` evaluates to `False` boolean-wise

so it'd end up like:

```
def merge_sort_list(lost_list):
    """splits the list in two parts until each part is left with one member"""
    x = len(lost_list) // 2
    if not x: # length is 1
        return lost_list
    else:
        return merge(merge_sort(lost_list[:x]), merge_sort(lost_list[x:]))
```

## Merge algorithm

For reuse later, I would use a more generic algorithm using `generators`, which doesn't alter the items passed into it. This will also help to make it easier to adapt the sorting algorithm for other containers

```
def merge(left, right):
    try:
        left = iter(left)
        right = iter(right)
        l = next(left)
        r = next(right)
    except StopIteration as exc:
        raise ValueError('left and right should be iterables with at least length 1', exc)
    try:
        while True:
            if l <= r:
                yield l
                l = None
                l = next(left)
            else:           
                yield r
                r = next(right)
    except StopIteration:
        yield r if l is None else l  # l is None if left is exhausted
        yield from left
        yield from right
        return
```

thanks to PeylonRayz for noticing the bug

## Alternative version

```
def merge(left, right):
    try:
        left = iter(left)
        right = iter(right)
        iterators = (
            (next(left), 'left', left), 
            (next(right), 'right', right),
        )
    except StopIteration as exc:
        raise ValueError('left and right should be iterables with at least length 1', exc)
    try:
        while True:
            (value, key, iterator), other = min(iterators), max(iterators)
            yield value
            iterators = other, (next(iterator), key, iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        value, key, iterator = other
        yield value
        yield from iterator
```

I find this alternative version is slightly more elegant, and in case of ex aequo, it keeps left before right. It can be easily adapted to support descending merging

## sorting dicts

```
def merge_sort_dict_keys(items):
    import collections
    sorted_keys = merge_sort_list(list(items.items()))
    return collections.OrderedDict((key, value) for key, value in sorted_keys)

def merge_sort_dict_values(items):
    import collections
    sorted_keys = merge_sort_list(list((value, key) for key, value in items.items()))
    return collections.OrderedDict((key, value) for value, key in sorted_keys)
```

Comment: I'm confused why you don't move the `while True` into the `try`, also if the last `l` is zero, then `yield l if l else r` won't work. Couldn't you instead use `max(l, r)`?